# Wireless WAN (WWAN) on a Lenovo T500 - built-in or do I need a WWAN modem?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, mobile-broadband

I use a [Lenovo ThinkPad 2055-3AU](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/quickPath.do?quickPathEntry=20553AU) at work and I want to get a Wireless WAN data plan with a local mobile telecom provider.

I've read conflicting reports online about whether my system is "WWAN-ready" or not. How can I find out which wireless WAN providers (if any) my system can support without buying a separate modem?

I looked through Device Manager for anything resembling a WWAN device and didn't see anything, but I also wiped the machine when I bought it and clean-installed Windows 7 with only out-of-the-box Windows and Windows-Update drivers, so it's possible that the device is there but the drivers aren't installed.

FWIW, the support page at http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/quickPath.do?quickPathEntry=20553AU does not specfically list anything about Wireless WAN.

Comment: i presume win7 is still like winXP when it comes to devices for which it doesn't have drivers -- you still see them in Device Manager, but there's a big question mark icon indicating that Windows doesn't have drivers for the device.  if you don't see any of those unidentified devices, you'd probably need a separate modem.

Comment: yep, you are correct-- it looks like I don't have a WWAN card. See my comment below. BTW, if you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it instead, since it's closer to being correct than @mspoerr's below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe hwinfo32 helps: http://www.hwinfo.com/

If there would be a built-in WWAN card available you would at least see some unknown devices in device manager.

Comment: I looked in HWInfo and Device Manager, and apparently the network card I have (the Intel 5100) is a WLAN-only, and doesn't include WiMax or other WWAN options. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

The majority of new T and W series Thinkpads are shipped as "WWAN Ready".  What this means is that they don't have the WWAN adapter (although they have the Mini-PCI slot available on the board for you to install an internal one, which is as easy as popping off the keyboard and connecting it) but they do already have a SIM card slot, which is generally under the battery.  Basically it's a shortcut so that if you DO decide to upgrade, you don't have to have an external Aircard and it's easier to change your SIM.